# Is there an Android emulator that emulates hardware components?

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, emulation, android-hardware

I am looking for an Android emulator that emulates the hardware components of the virtual device, such as CPU, memory, battery and so on. I need to know the usage of these components made by an application and how it changes over time.

Can I do it with the official Android emulator or is there another one that allows me to do that? Or any hardware virtualization tool? And how can I check the performance of the apps on the emulator?

Comment: I think if you are using Android Studio, you can open the "Android Device Monitor" to see these things.

Comment: Yes, I already knew it, but It lets me monitor only the developed application. I want to monitor many different applications, in particular malwares.